# Vertices of Rectangle with midline given in lat long

Tags: gis, latitude-longitude, bounding-box

In my program, I have end points of a line segment in lat-long(so width is known). I want to know vertices of the rectangle having this line segment as its middle line(not diagonal). I also know the height of the rectangle.

Is there a java API available for it? Or do I need to code it?

Manish

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Topology Suite. See https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/index.html

There you can perform a buffer on this line, which returns a rectangle, and this line is the middle of this rectangle (not diagonal).